# How does the compiler handle overloaded function call operators in functors?

Tags: c++, function, constructor, call, overloading

Say I define, instantiate, and use an adder functor like so:

```
class SomeAdder {
    public:
        SomeAdder(int init_x): x(init_x) {}
        void operator()(int num) { cout << x + num <<endl; }
    private:
        int x;
};

SomeAdder a = SomeAdder (3);
a(5); //Prints 8

SomeAdder b(5);
b(5); //Prints 10
```

The constructor and the overloaded `()` operator are both called using double parenthesis and have the same types of parameters. How would the compiler determine which function to use during the instantiations of `SomeAdder` and the "function calls", as to implement the correct behavior? The answer seems like it would be obvious on the surface, but I just can't wrap my head around this thought.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The same way it distinguishes `f(x)` from `g(x)` where `void f(int); void g(int)` ;-)

Comment: If the compiler sees `SomeAdder(...)`, then how could it think it's a call to an `operator()` if `SomeAdder` is a type?

Comment: To be honest I remember being confused by this too, initially, way back when.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example compares *constructor* and *member function* which overloads `operator()`. The compiler knows which one to call and when. It is pretty much simple:

- When an object is to be constructed, the constructor is called.
- The member function is invoked on an already constructed object. In your case, the member function is `operator()`.

That means, they're invoked in entirely different contexts. There is no ambiguity, no confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Every time an instance of a class is created the constructor method is called. Compiler for sure can determine constructor by its name. So it will be called first and `operator ()` will be second.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has a [grammar](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb) and from that the compiler will know(gross simplification) when a type is being instantiated and therefore a constructor should be called from the case where an overloaded operator `()` is being called on an instance of a class.

How the grammar is used to determine this probably requires a course on compilers which the [Dragon Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811) is probably the standard. If you are curious you can also check out the [C++ Grandmaster Certification](http://www.cppgm.org) whose goal is to build a C++ compiler.